# Creating a ctrl A Delimiter file

Tags: linux, file, filesystems

How to create a record in a file with delimiter as ctrl A.

Lets have a file name is records.txt

I need some records to be created with each attribute in that each record should be ctrl A delimited.. How to create it

```
surender,raja,chennai
kumar,ajay,chennai
```

As you can see there are 2 records . each record is comma delimited. Simlarly I need ctrlA delimiter

Comment: What do you mean wirth "ctrl A"?

Comment: it is a delimiter just like comma or pipe symbol(|) .. the ascii form for ctrl A is '/u0001'

Comment: And what have you tried so far? And create record from what? Where from?

Comment: I tried like this  surrender^A100^Achennai

Comment: what language are you writing code for? tag accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using GCC and C++. You will need to use a string, not a char.

```
"\u0001"
```

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
   std::ofstream out("foo.tmp");
   out << "\u0001";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually ... tested with char and it worked fine for me.